# restoration of oracle database

Tags: oracle10g

Can i restore different dumps(databases) on a single database created through the database configuration assistant in oracle 10g.
i mean to say that the previous tablespaces must be overwritten by the new one thus saving the time to create new tablespace everytime we restore a dump file.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possile by creating a new user.the new user will act as a new schema and can exist with the previously imported data without overwriting it.
how ever if i want to import different data using the same user  then the previously stored data must be dropped along with the user first,the agin the user must be created;
Command to do this is

DROP USER  CASCADE;
This will drop the previously stored data without deleting the tablespaces thus saving time to create new tablespaces.